# COUNTIF/COUNTIFS with text containing characters and OR logic doesn't work as expected

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following column example in google sheets, and I'm trying to see how many people ( in Column B I have names ) - will be left *out* if I'll choose certain days:

```
     A
-----------
s, m
m, w
s, m
```

So basically if I'll choose day `f`( Friday ) or `t` (Tue) - all people won't be able to attend
If I'll choose day `f` or `w` - only one person will be able to attend.

Following the below example from the docs, the brackets `{}` suppose to do `OR` - but the results doesn't make sense at all

- `f` or `t` `=COUNTIF(A1:A3, {"*f*", "*t*"})` - return 0
- `m` or `s` `=COUNTIF(A1:A3, {"*m*", "*s*"})` - returns 3
- `w` or `s` `=COUNTIF(A1:A3, {"*w*", "*s*"})` - for some reason return 1 ( vs 3 )
- but if I flip the order - `s` or `w` `=COUNTIF(A1:A3, {"*s*", "*w*"})` - for some reason return 2 ( ?! )

What's going on  ?

Looking at https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/excel-chat/excel-tutorial/countifs/countifs-with-multiple-criteria-and-or-logic

it says `count items which have the month January or March` ( OR `{"January", "March"}` )

```
Count Items with Multiple Criteria and Or Logic
In our example, we want to count items which have the month January or March and Product ID 1001 or 1002.

The formula looks like:

=SUM(COUNTIFS(B3:B13, {"1001", "1002"}, C3:C13, {"January", "March"}))

The parameter criteria_range1 is B3:B13 and the criteria1 is the array  {“1001”, “1002”}. The parameter criteria_range2 is C3:C13 and the criteria2 is {“January”, “March”}. The result of this COUNTIFS function is 2 numbers, which are number parameters of the SUM function.
```

Comment: Sidenote, please either choose Excel or Google Sheets in your tags, not both since they work differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not that strange at all. With `{}` you are creating an array of values. Since you probably don't have Excel O365, you'd see the implicit intersection of the returned array, or with other words the **first** value.

In your example `=COUNTIF(A1:A3, {"*w*", "*s*"})`, the resulting array is `{1,2}` since `*w*` exists just once and `*s*` twice. So the implicit intersection of this array shows you just `1`. If you swap the criteria obviously you'd see `2`.

In this case you'd normally use `SUM(COUNTIF(A1:A3, {"*w*", "*s*"}))` to return `3`. But beware that doing so will return `5` for `SUM(COUNTIF(A1:A3, {"*m*", "*s*"}))`, since it's resulting array will be `{3,2}`. So, in the case of comma-delimited values I'd choose a little bit of a different approach.

If you are using Google Spreadsheets, maybe something along the lines of:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(A:A,"Select Count(A) where A like '%s%' or A like '%x%' label Count(A) ''"),0)
```

does what you want?

Comment: I don't mind using other approach - what did you have in mind ? ( I tried many things until I wrote this question )

Comment: @RickyLevi, I've updated my answer with a possible solution.

Comment: strange, if I give: `=COUNTA(QUERY(A:A,"Select A where A like '%f%' or A like '%x%'"))` ( values that doesn't exists ) - the result is 1 (?)

Comment: @RickyLevi, I see what I did wrong. It's returning an error which does get counted by COUNTA. Let's put the count in the actual query this time and wrap it with an `IFERROR`. =)